$P(A|C)=0.05$ and $P(B|C)=0.05\implies P(A \cap B|C)=(0.05)^2$


Let $A, B$, and $C$ be events such that $P(A|C)=0.05$ and $P(B|C)=0.05$. Then is it true that $P(A \cap B|C)=(0.05)^2$?


I think that I need to show that $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C).$
Given $P(A\cap B|C)$, we have by definition $$\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}.$$
And, assuming that $A,B,C$ are mutually exclusive events,
$$\frac{P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A\cap B)}{P(C)}$$
$$P(B\cap A)\frac{P(C|A\cap B)}{P(C)}$$
I really don't know what to do next.

If $A=B$, then $P(A\cap B\mid C) = P(A\mid C) = 0.05$.

With your assumption that $A,B,C$ are mutually exclusive events, then both $P(A\mid C)$ and $P(B\mid C)$ would be $0$.

It's only true if $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent on $C$ (this is the definition of conditional independence). Generally it's not true (even unconditional independence of $A$ and $B$ isn't enough).
If the question is really "is it (always) true that ...", then the answer is "no" and you should come up with a counterexample.

Consider these events associated with tossing a $20$-sided fair die:
$A=\{1\}\\
B=\{2\}\\
C=\{1,2,\ldots,20\}.$
